# Using Transaction Scope with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I have two tables. First table contains some data. Second table contains history of data changes. First table also contains column which reference to last history row. When data from row in first table has being changed, copy is inserted in second table and in first column which reference to last data copy is updated. For that I use this code

```
using (TransactionScope trn = new TransactionScope())
{
  Table1 t1=model.Table1.Where(t=>t==id).FirstOrDefault();
  /*update Table1 data*/
  Table2 t2=new Table2();
  t2.Table1=t1;
  model.AddToTable2(t2);
  /*set Table2 fields*/
  model.SaveChanges();

  t1.ref=t2.id;
  model.SaveChanges();
  trn.Complete();
}
```

Usage of TransactionScope for save conform data is rigth? Or i need use othe method?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need saving changes twice? If the tables are related you should be able to set navigation properties and save all the changes just once. In that case you would not need to create a transaction on your own - EF would create one for you. If you need to save changes twice TransactionScope should do the trick. The connection is enlisted into transaction when being opened. In the code snippet you don't show how your context is instantiated and what happens with the connection before it gets to the transaction so it is hard to tell whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score -1):

Context class by default support transactions. but with every new instance of context class, a new transaction will be created. This new transaction is a nested transaction and it will get committed once the SaveChanges() on the associated context class gets called.

In this case we don't even need TransactionScope. We can simply check for result of both operations and if they are successful, we simply need to call SaveChanges() method.

TransactionScope is usually needed when we are mixing ADO.NET calls with Entity framework. The trick for using TransactionScope in such cases is to let the context class know that you want to use it with your own transaction. Since the transaction gets associated with the connection object in the scope, we need to use the context class with the connection that is being associated with the transaction scope. Also, we need to let the context class know that it cannot own the connection as it is being owned by the calling code. so we can do something like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
{ 
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 

        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
        sqlCommand.Connection = conn; 
        sqlCommand.CommandText = 
            @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" + 
                " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'"; 
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        using (var context = 
            new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
        { 
            var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating > 5); 
            foreach (var post in query) 
            { 
                post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
            } 
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        } 
    } 

    scope.Complete(); 
}
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx